# error: field 'dateOfBirth' has incomplete type 'Poco::Data::Date'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, poco, poco-libraries

I am trying to use POCO library to store date of birth.

```
#include <Poco/DateTime.h>
#include <Poco/Data/Time.h>
```

```
void main()
{
   Poco::Data::Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

But while compilation I am getting Error :

error: field 'dateOfBirth' has incomplete type 'Poco::Data::Date'

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Poco/Data/Date.h>
```

This header file should be included